# Ac lines a frosted a bit and fan not blowing as hard

Tags: hvac

My ac line has a bit of frost on it and isn't blowing as hard. This has happened 3 times now. So I turn cool off and just run the fan for an hour and it works fine for a few days. I've changed the air filter last week. My coil I know has a leak I had it checked when I had refrigerate put in around may. My question is what could it be ?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Thank you! I know I have a leak but, this doesn't seem like low refrigerant  what could it be. I had freon filled in May

Comment: Low freon.  Just because you had it filled in May doesn't mean it's not low now.

Comment: Yep, low freon can cause the evaporator coil to be excessively cold, causing it to ice up on the outside.

Comment: Freon won't cause the fan to change speed. Well, ice might.  I'd also check for a power problem.

Comment: @Harper - frozen evaporator coil inside = no air flow. ... What "it could be" is either a new unit, or bad for the environment filling it every three months. Your pocket book will decide. Just don't forget that it's expensive to be poor.

Comment: Or it could be the A coil fixed and up and running

Answer (score 1):

If the outside of the evaporator has a build up of ice on it, the fan wont be able to blow air through the evaporator so you will get a drop in flow.

Turning the AC off will allow the ice to melt and hence it will work correctly again when you turn it back on.

Is the evaporator able to drain condensation ok?

Comment: Would it work for days at a time? Cause the last time was like a week ago or more and it happened about a week before that. I'll check the evaporator drain.

Comment: You need to get the charge replenished, that is what is causing your problems as I can determine from what you said. The real solution is to get the leak fixed or expect this to happen on a regular basis. As time passes it will get worse then no AC.